# Getting "HTTP Error 403: Forbidden" error when download MNIST dataset

Tags: python, torchvision

I use following code to get the MNIST dataset:

```
import torchvision.datasets
MNIST_train = torchvision.datasets.MNIST('./', download=True, train=True)
```

This code worked times ago, but now it shows the error:

```
Downloading http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz to ./MNIST\raw\train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
Stack trace:
 >  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
 >    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
```

Answer (score 13):

Using the suggestion mentioned [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/1938), adding this to the top of my script worked:

```
from six.moves import urllib    
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems you may have to add a header to your urllib request (due to that site moving to Cloudflare protection)

Eg.

```
opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.addheader('User-Agent', some_user_agent)
opener.retrieve(
    url, fpath,
    reporthook=gen_bar_updater()
)
```

This problem is mentioned in a github forum for pytorch [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/1938) as well, with a few solutions for the issue.

One of the more complete Python3 solutions given there is as follows:

```
from torchvision import datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import urllib

num_workers = 0
batch_size = 20
basepath = 'some/base/path'
transform = transforms.ToTensor()

def set_header_for(url, filename):
    opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
    opener.addheader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36')
    opener.retrieve(
    url, f'{basepath}/{filename}')

set_header_for('http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz', 'train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')
set_header_for('http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz', 'train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')
set_header_for('http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz', 't10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')
set_header_for('http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz', 't10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')
train_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=True,
                                   download=True, transform=transform)
test_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', train=False,
                                  download=False, transform=transform)
```

They add the header for each of the retrievals using a function, simplifying the process.

Comment: @Kola73 no problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

I looked it up and the problem is that the folder has moved under CloudFlare protection as one of the commentors mentions here: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/1938.

It is also explained how to solve/fix this issue by adding headers there. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Kim, providing urls in answers is useful, but it would be more helpful to provide steps in the answer as well, due to how links can break, but answers on the site will remain. Will upvote you if you decide to improve your response.

Comment: Thanks, it helps :)